# Move a forum from a directory to a subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I'd like to move my old forum to a subdomain, but It doesn't work...

My forum is IPB 3.2 (invision power board), and at that point i've created my subdomain (not using CPanel, DNS propagated), and followed their instructions.

My homepage works fine and the new links are OK, but when I try to view a topic i get an error 500.

For example, when i try to view this page :
http://forum.domain.com/my-topic-t1.html

I got an error, and here is what's in my error log:

```
//my-topic-t1.html HTTP/1.1" 500 403 "http://forum.domain.com/
```

I guess it's a mod rewrite problem, but i can't figure out what's wrong.

Here is my .htaccess file (located in my /forum/ folder)

```
RewriteBase /forum/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /forum/index.php [L]
```

I've been told it may be an issue with the rewrite rule and the way the sub-domain is configured/being served. But how to put an exception in for the sub-domain ?

I'm on a shared server running Apache2.

Thanks !

Comment: My subdomain 'forum' points into the '/forum/' folder (root).
Complete log I have is:
`xx.xxx.xx.xxx - - [16/Aug/2011:12:18:56 +0200] "GET //my-topic-t1.html HTTP/1.1" 500 403 "http://forum.domain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"`
sorry I don't have anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because subdomain already points into `/forum/` folder, you need to remove that part from the rewrite rule target (as well as get rid of the RewriteBase).

Try this line instead:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```